# DataGridViewAutoFilter Resize Column Header Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wrote one project. I used `DataGridViewAutoFilter` library for filtering. But I have problem.

For filtering Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView Column Header Cell size(width) are very small. It come automatic size.

How to resize Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView Column Header Cell for filtering?

```
private void dataGridView1_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null) return; 
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) 
    { 
        col.HeaderCell = new DataGridViewAutoFilterColumnHeaderCell(col.HeaderCell); 
    } 
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; 
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Put your sample code and show your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : We must change SetDropDownList properties : DataGridViewColumnHeader.cs in DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll.İt is open source.

```
 private void SetDropDownListBoxBounds()
        {
            Debug.Assert(filters.Count > 0, "filters.Count <= 0");

            // Declare variables that will be used in the calculation, 
            // initializing dropDownListBoxHeight to account for the 
            // ListBox borders.
            Int32 dropDownListBoxHeight = 6; // You must change!!!!!
            Int32 currentWidth = 0;
            Int32 dropDownListBoxWidth = 0;
            Int32 dropDownListBoxLeft = 0;

            // For each formatted value in the filters dictionary Keys collection,
            // add its height to dropDownListBoxHeight and, if it is wider than 
            // all previous values, set dropDownListBoxWidth to its width.
            using (Graphics graphics = dropDownListBox.CreateGraphics())
            {
                foreach (String filter in filters.Keys)
                {
                    SizeF stringSizeF = graphics.MeasureString(
                        filter, dropDownListBox.Font);
                    dropDownListBoxHeight += (Int32)stringSizeF.Height;
                    currentWidth = (Int32)stringSizeF.Width;
                    if (dropDownListBoxWidth < currentWidth)
                    {
                        dropDownListBoxWidth = currentWidth;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Increase the width to allow for horizontal margins and borders. 
            dropDownListBoxWidth += 40; //You must change !!!

            // Constrain the dropDownListBox height to the 
            // DropDownListBoxMaxHeightInternal value, which is based on 
            // the DropDownListBoxMaxLines property value but constrained by
            // the maximum height available in the DataGridView control.
            if (dropDownListBoxHeight > DropDownListBoxMaxHeightInternal)
            {
                dropDownListBoxHeight = DropDownListBoxMaxHeightInternal;

                // If the preferred height is greater than the available height,
                // adjust the width to accommodate the vertical scroll bar. 
                dropDownListBoxWidth += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
            }

            // Calculate the ideal location of the left edge of dropDownListBox 
            // based on the location of the drop-down button and taking the 
            // RightToLeft property value into consideration. 
            if (this.DataGridView.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No)
            {
                dropDownListBoxLeft = DropDownButtonBounds.Right - 
                    dropDownListBoxWidth + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dropDownListBoxLeft = DropDownButtonBounds.Left - 1;
            }

            // Determine the left and right edges of the available horizontal
            // width of the DataGridView control. 
            Int32 clientLeft = 1;
            Int32 clientRight = this.DataGridView.ClientRectangle.Right;
            if (this.DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(false) < 
                this.DataGridView.RowCount)
            {
                if (this.DataGridView.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                {
                    clientLeft += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    clientRight -= SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
                }
            }

            // Adjust the dropDownListBox location and/or width if it would
            // otherwise overlap the left or right edge of the DataGridView.
            if (dropDownListBoxLeft < clientLeft)
            {
                dropDownListBoxLeft = clientLeft;
            }
            Int32 dropDownListBoxRight = 
                dropDownListBoxLeft + dropDownListBoxWidth + 1;
            if (dropDownListBoxRight > clientRight)
            {
                if (dropDownListBoxLeft == clientLeft)
                {
                    dropDownListBoxWidth -=
                        dropDownListBoxRight - clientRight;
                }
                else
                {
                    dropDownListBoxLeft -=
                        dropDownListBoxRight - clientRight;
                    if (dropDownListBoxLeft < clientLeft)
                    {
                        dropDownListBoxWidth -= clientLeft - dropDownListBoxLeft;
                        dropDownListBoxLeft = clientLeft;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set the ListBox.Bounds property using the calculated values. 
            dropDownListBox.Bounds = new Rectangle(dropDownListBoxLeft,
                DropDownButtonBounds.Bottom, // top of drop-down list box
                dropDownListBoxWidth, dropDownListBoxHeight);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the actual maximum height of the drop-down list, in pixels.
        /// The maximum height is calculated from the DropDownListBoxMaxLines 
        /// property value, but is limited to the available height of the 
        /// DataGridView c`enter code here`ontrol.
```